# LVM: duplicate PVs were found

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have 3node cluster(centos7), While installing glusterfs and heketi i found issue of duplicate pv in LV.

```
[centos@master-node ~]$ sudo pvs
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  WARNING: Use multipath or vgimportclone to resolve duplicate PVs?
  WARNING: After duplicates are resolved, run "pvscan --cache" to enable lvmetad.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop1 for PV tJno1Q-hyH5-BtA5-j04f-XOui-wMUS-7Rn4V7.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop2 for PV tJno1Q-hyH5-BtA5-j04f-XOui-wMUS-7Rn4V7.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop9 for PV tJno1Q-hyH5-BtA5-j04f-XOui-wMUS-7Rn4V7.
  WARNING: PV tJno1Q-hyH5-BtA5-j04f-XOui-wMUS-7Rn4V7 prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV tJno1Q-hyH5-BtA5-j04f-XOui-wMUS-7Rn4V7 prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV tJno1Q-hyH5-BtA5-j04f-XOui-wMUS-7Rn4V7 prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/loop0 recover1 lvm2 a--   239.87g <237.85g
  /dev/sda2  centos   lvm2 a--   390.00g       0
  /dev/sdb   centos   lvm2 a--  <100.00g    1.00g


[centos@master-node ~]$ sudo lvs
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  WARNING: Use multipath or vgimportclone to resolve duplicate PVs?
  WARNING: After duplicates are resolved, run "pvscan --cache" to enable lvmetad.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop1 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop2 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop9 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  LV                                     VG      Attr       LSize   Pool                                Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home                                   centos  -wi-ao----  90.00g
  root                                   centos  -wi-ao---- 399.00g
  brick_3108b8903c1ef1cfd8a2aacddb02b30d recover Vwi---tz--   2.00g tp_3108b8903c1ef1cfd8a2aacddb02b30d
  tp_3108b8903c1ef1cfd8a2aacddb02b30d    recover twi---tz--   2.00g


[centos@master-node ~]$ sudo vgdisplay
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  WARNING: Use multipath or vgimportclone to resolve duplicate PVs?
  WARNING: After duplicates are resolved, run "pvscan --cache" to enable lvmetad.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop1 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop2 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop9 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               490.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              125440
  Alloc PE / Size       125184 / 489.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       256 / 1.00 GiB
  VG UUID               2rXrFU-zzc5-semj-qfep-TwKw-wEGq-S46pFR

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               recover
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               239.87 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              61407
  Alloc PE / Size       518 / 2.02 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       60889 / <237.85 GiB
  VG UUID               VmxXUO-IDmA-OxHZ-K3v3-rFe7-Hc0Z-KcZbH0
```

I tried running below command to fix it, but looks like it is not working...      WARNING: Failed to scan devices.
https://sontsysadmin.blogspot.com/2017/09/mounting-lvm-with-same-pv-lv-vg-names.html?_sm_au_=i5V21DP5FTWnq7jRML8tvK34L00HF

```
[centos@master-node ~]$ sudo vgimportclone --basevgname recover /dev/loop1
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop1 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop2 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: Not using device /dev/loop9 for PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: PV GgwJoD-TzcN-LFts-CohB-LRIY-K2tl-qD0nXF prefers device /dev/loop0 because device is used by LV.
  WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/loop0
  WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/loop2
  WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/loop9
  WARNING: Disabling lvmetad cache which does not support duplicate PVs.
  WARNING: Scan found duplicate PVs.
  WARNING: Failed to scan devices.
  WARNING: Update lvmetad with pvscan --cache.
```

I pretty new to linux administration specially lvm. Please help fix this issue.any pointer would be help ful.